# Localhost can't currently handle this request

Tags: asp.net, database

I built a ASP. NET core web application project and connected to a Azure SQL database. The project is built with no problems, but when I try to register to the web application, it gives the following error in the browser.

> This page isn't working right now localhost can't currently handle
>
> this request.
>
> HTTP ERROR 500

but the database is up and running though it gives 500 https status code.

The URL of the redirected page is as follows.

```
https://localhost:44322/Identity/Account/ExternalLogin?handler=Callback
```

Can somebody please help me to find the issue, please?

Following is the connection string. I have hide the password. I have put the following string in apsettings.js file.

```
"MyDbConnection": "Server=tcp:mydbconnection.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=mydbs;User ID=AdminNicolai;Password=;Encrypt=True;"
```

Comment: 500 is an indication that the server-side code (i.e. the asp.net code in this case) crashed. Check your error log.

Comment: Yes, I checked. database is up and running. I restarted it again and again too. But, I will check again. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: It may be nothing to do with the database

Answer (score 2):

ExternalLogin page is used to register/login with external app (ex. Facebook, Google accounts). You have to configure the credentials for them to work.
Also check if you have all the tables in DB necessarily for authentication.